# Firestore updates are received with high latency when security rules are enabled

Tags: javascript, performance, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I'm experiencing an issue with firebase firestore db rules. I have a quite standard messaging application and i have a data model structured as follows

```
[conversations] / Conversation / [messages] / Message
```

Conversation objects have an map {participants_ids: true` to express membership as well as other application specific data.
I've setup my rules in this way

```
match /conversations/{conversationID} {

  allow read, update: if request.auth != null && resource.data.participants[request.auth.uid] == true;
  // creation case is omitted for brevity

  match /messages/{messageID} {

    allow read, create: if request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/conversations/$(conversationID)).data.participants[request.auth.uid] == true;

  }
}
```

When these rules are enabled, i experience a surprisingly constant 30 seconds delay between db modifications 
(e.g. new message in `messages` collection or update of `Conversation` object from admin interface or functions) and the corresponding event in js-sdk (angularfire). 
If I disable those rules, latency disappears. I tested different combination of rule conditions and the only case without latency is when both matches have `allow read, write;` body.
Has somebody already experienced the same problem? Are you aware of some request throttling when rules are involved?

Many thanks

Edit:

I created a minimal version recreating the issue. Code is available at https://github.com/pveglia/firestore-rules-performance and deployed here https://firestore-rules-issue.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Hmmm... in my experience security rules don't impact performance that much. But that means it might depends on the data structure, actual rules, and how you read the data. Can you edit your question to include the [actual code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?